# SlickGrid with Zurb Foundation

Tags: slickgrid, zurb-foundation

Has anyone sucessfully implemented slickgrid.js (spreadsheet/datatable type "grid") with a css "grid" framework?  Confusing use of the word grid, I know...

I am attempting to use it within zurb foundation and the table div required for slickgrid.js to render properly is overrunning everything from a width standpoint, which appears to be automatically set by the javascript.

Answer (score 2):

I did manage to make work slickgrid with foundation. What problem do you have?.
I'm using foundation 3.2 and slickgrid 2.1.
Only have to make two fixes on CSS:

```
#myGrid * {
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
#myGrid [class*="column"]:last-child {
  float: none;
}
```

Testing on Firefox it behaves differently, so is necessary to add

```
.slick-header-column {
   -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
   box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Because on line 548 of slick.grid.js it gets the width from a div not attached to the DOM.